# ModelBinder and Dates in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

All the dates in my URLs come in this format: `dd-MM-yyyy`. Example: 31-12-2017

Currently, my Web API has a method like this

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IAsyncResult> GetSomething([FromQuery] date) 
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that my Web API seems work ONLY with dates formatted in **US English**.

- A date like **12-31-2017** will work.
- Whereas a date like **31-12-2017** won't work.

How can I make it bind my custom data format from the query to the injected parameter?

Comment: You might want to check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am submitting this for ASP core 2.0 in the startup.cs add

```
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {

                        new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                        new CultureInfo("ar")
                };


                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-GB", uiCulture: "en-GB");


            });
```

this will make the model binding accept the format dd/MM/yyy

Comment: Not sure why opts.DefaultRequestCulture is there twice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom Model Binder to accomplish this. Here is a sample code:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime));

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            //  valueAsString will have a string value of your date, e.g. '31-12-2017'
            //  Parse it as you need and build DateTime object
            var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(valueAsString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dateTime);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public Task<IAsyncResult> GetSomething([FromQuery] [ModelBinder(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))] date) 
{
    ...
}
```